# Getting data from python child process to Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I have some code in **Python** and I am invoking the Python code from `Node.js`. I am able to get the code executed, however I am stuck with getting the data streamed from Python to **node.js**.

Help me in identifying how to stream the data to `node.js`.

P.S I am new to both Python and Node.js

Comment: Please post some code so we can see how far you gotten so that you can get a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing this right now? It sounds like you should be using the [Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) libraries.

Are you using `exec` or `spawn`? They both work slightly differently, but they have either a callback (`exec`) or events that fire when data is received (`spawn`).

The examples on that page are pretty explicit. Is there something specific in those examples that you don't understand? Is there some sample code that you could provide to clarify your problem?

Comment: I am using spawn and now i am getting the data. It is working pretty well with just print itself. Thanks for your help.